# Windows blocks downloads from server "Blocked by your organization"

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-registry, windows-11, group-policy

I recently started having an issue on Windows 11 where when I try downloading a file, all of my browsers refuse to do so displaying this: (images are from Chrome)

[image: Downloads example]

As you can see, files that I try to download from my server are blocked no matter the extension, but one file with the same extension from `colab.research.google.com` works absolutely fine.

Here is the error expanded:

[image]

If that's relevant, I am downloading from my `Jupyter Lab` server, which has a link like: `http://204.159.145.71:8888/lab/tree/` (maybe it doesn't like that it's `http`, or that it is an IP address, but it used to be fine).

This is really strange to me because I have all the safe browsing set to "disabled".

This really looks to me like some kind of restriction in the registry editor, but I have no idea where that may be hiding.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Is this error on downloads from one particular web-server?

Comment: It may also be that they are not blocking your server specifically, but traffic over port 8888. If you have the ability to alter the port, maybe that will make it work again.

Comment: @harrymc Seems to be, yeah. Other sites work fine as far as I can tell

Comment: @LPChip I can't do anything about the port, besides, 8888 is the port that server is listening to, not my computer, why would it care?

Comment: Your IP department may have setup a port filter to block most ports and keep certain traffic only to standard ports, like 80 and 443.

Comment: I suspect that something is blocking HTTP downloads. Try to disable (temporarily) your firewall and security software and test.

Comment: @harrymc No result, unfortunately

Comment: A final test of my idea would be to add an SSL certificate to the Jupyter Lab server and test if HTTPS works.

Comment: Try creating a new Chrome user profile, then download the file, if the download is still being downloaded then you have inadvertently allowed your company to apply Chromium AD group policies to your machine.

Comment: @Ramhound Other user works fine, all the same files are downloaded without issues lol

Comment: @user9102437 - So you have confirmed it’s a Chrome setting that is blocking the download

Comment: I'm encountering this same issue since some days ago where *.exe file downloads are blocked due to 'organisation policy' on both Chrome and Edge, but work just fine on Firefox. And just like OP here, it's my own personal computer that doesn't have any work related data. I'm on Windows 10 and I'm suspecting a bad Windows update.

Answer (score 3):

This error is not all about Organizations and Policies. It may falsely come from a failed download take over by an extension.
After a long time of headache I was able to solve this by disabling an extension.
The culprit was the "IDM Integration Module" which connects Chrome/Edge to the "Internet Download Manager" software. You can disable this until a fix comes out.

Settings Menu > Extensions > Manage Extensions > IDM Integration Module > Disable

If you don't have IDM installed look for an extension which may want to manipulate or take over downloads.

Answer (score 2):

Up front: there is no "disabled" option for safe browsing in Chrome, are you sure you used the right setting?

Check if your PC is part of a Domain by using Powershell:

```
if ((gwmi win32_computersystem).partofdomain -eq $true) {write-host "DOM"} else {write-host "WG"}
```

If the output is `DOM`, you are not using a "personal" account, change your computer from Domain to workgroup.

If the output is `WG` then it depends on whether the file is downloaded or not:

- if it is downloaded: the next step is to right-click the file in question. Under the general tab, towards the bottom right, is there an “unblock” option? If so, and it’s checked out, uncheck it, and try again.
- if it's not downloaded:

  - Go to Google Chrome Settings
  - Select `Privacy and Security`
  - Select `Security`
  - Select the `No protection (not recommended)` option

Make sure you turn on the `Standard protection` after you’ve downloaded the blocked files.

Comment: "No protection" is what I meant by "disabled", so this does not help the issue. But your code printed out "WG"

Comment: @user9102437 Are the files being downloaded at all? Maybe as a temporary file or into a temp directory etc.?

Comment: No, chrome refuses to even start, if I open `chrome://downloads` its just says: "Failed - Blocked" on this file. Its name is shown in grey and is not clickable. I can, however, click on the link and see the raw file's content.

Comment: @user9102437 so if you can see "raw file content" it means the download did start, can you please specify?!

Comment: No, this only opens on the website, kind of like raw content on github. If the file were to be actually downloaded, I would see something like `file://filename.txt`, but I see the link to the server instead. This means that is is treated just like a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer is attached to organization domain. And admin deploy some group policies to deny specific downloads. You can't change/remove these limitations if you do not have admin/domain account.

What you can do is to contact support and raise a ticket about permit some downloads.

Comment: But this is my personal laptop, I am the admin . Perhaps you could walk me through the process of removing those limitations? I have full access

Comment: @user9102437 even a laptop where you are the admin can still be managed, if your work placed it in their domain. The message suggests blocked by policy. You can try a different browser in combination with a VPN

Comment: @LPChip I work from home, so it is my network too :) . But I tried using a VPN. Didn't help

Comment: I said VPN in combination with another browser.

Comment: @user9102437, did you add your working account there?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I don't have a working account. My network is not connected to any type of organization at all (except the ISP of course)

Comment: @LPChip I did use Edge when testing this

Comment: Edge, Chrome and all other Chromium browsers, can be managed with a policy. How about trying firefox.

Comment: @user9102437, never the less check in Settings->Accounts

Comment: Are you using a VPN?

Comment: @Albin No, no VPN, but I tried it too

Comment: @LPChip Downloaded Firefox, downloads now work without issues, but I would still like to fix Chrome

Comment: @RomeoNinov Could you please elaborate? I have opened setting->accounts on Windows, and there is only one account (mine) and it is marked as an Administrator

Comment: @user9102437, this was the check I talk about.

Comment: Chrome is out of the question as these are blocked by a company policy. You have an alternative way to get the files. So either live with this, or get your IT department to unblock your server.

Comment: @LPChip Why do you keep tryna tell me that I need to contact the IT department. This is my house and I own the server, I AM the IT department

Comment: The message says that a policy is enabled that blocks this. Policies can either be group policy from a domain or local policy. Both are things a regular user would not enforce so the logical thing is that its pushed through by a company. This can be done by an Active Directory, or even if your computer was joined with AzureAD (now known as Microsoft Entra) and the GPO was pushed from there.

Comment: @LPChip Microsoft lied in that message. I save the same issue: my own computer, my own local network, the computer never joined a domain or accessed work accounts, I’m the only administrator, yet MS Edge default policies arbitrarily blocking some web sites on the internets. Firefox works fine, BTW.

Comment: @Soonts a domain is the most possible cause, but not the only one. You can change a regkey to get the same behavior. Some apps, such as virusscanners will also do this. I suspect you have third party software installed that does this to your computer.

Comment: @LPChip  No third-party security related software is installed, I’m using  windows defender firewall, and the OS built-in virus protection.

Answer (score -1):

As already suggested thi is because your organization has set up security policies to protect its devices and networks. These policies can block certain types of files from being downloaded, such as executable files (.exe), or files from specific websites.

A few reasons why your organization may have blocked the file:

The file is from a website that is known to be untrustworthy.
The file type is blocked by your organization's security policy.

You can try the following if you are sure its safe:

- Contact your IT administrator and ask them to unblock the file for
  you.
- Try downloading the file from a different website.
- download the file on a differnt device and transfer via USB
- Rename the file extension to one that is not blocked by your organization's
  security policy.

Does your company use anything like censornet? I know mine was blocking all downloads and certain "Non productive" sites like Amazon until I sweet talked the IT Manager to white list me ;-)